# Can I replicate discord activity status on my website with just frontend?

Tags: javascript, html, css, discord

Hello I've been working on a portfolio and I was thinking maybe adding live updates of my Discord profile (`Online`, `DND`, `Idle` or `Invisible`) would be possible.

If viewing my site so far helps better understand my question you can visit it [here](https://unofficialdxnny.netlify.app)

and the source code can be found [here.](https://github.com/unofficialdxnny/unofficialdxnny-website)

As you can see I have setup a about me on the left side, I would like some code to check if Im online on Discord than change the outline of my profile picture to be `Green` and so on with the others.

I have currently tried nothing but imagination since I am not too sure how I can communicate with Discord from my site.

Here is a view of what I currently have:

[image]

This is what I would like to achieve:

[image: Idle on DC]

Answer (score -3):

Although using a discord bot can be a good way of monitoring and replicating this activity anybody else trying to do this should loock into the [lanyard API](https://github.com/Phineas/lanyard). This allows users to get all of their discord activities into a json format and according to their needs use in their websites.